# Laravel getting Umlauts from mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

At the moment I have difficulty getting the correct value from Databases.

It is about German Umlauts like äöü and so on. I need Umlauts to be shown at the Sourcecode, because they have to be executed on another PC.

Here is the code:

```
$script = DB::table('scripttemplates')->where('id','=',$_x->template_id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->take(1)->get();
        //$script = utf8_encode($script_temp);


        foreach ($script as $_z) {
            echo $_z->script;
```

The Problem: the Umlauts are saved correctly in the Databese, however, if I try to get these from the Database they look like this Ã¶"

Appreciate any help!

Comment: which collation for db is used?

Comment: Hey it is UTF8.

Comment: As fast fix - http://codepad.org/BeBWDHV5

Comment: Thx i will try that

Comment: Also that did not work :(

Comment: I've found the problem. Apache was not set to UTF-8